# Is there a way to make VS pro insert a dummy code lens?

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, codelens

We have a mix of VS 2013 Ultimate & Pro in our project. That leads to a problem:

When writing with Ultimate we have stopped adding empty lines between properties & methods because the code lens inserts ~empty rows~ (see pic).

[image: Empty lines provided by code lense]

The problem is that it looks like a wall of code when someone using VS Pro reads it without the lens thing.

Question: Is there a way to get VS 2013 Pro to insert empty rows where the code lens would insert its stuff?

Comment: You could always disable code lens on the Ultimate editions ;)

Comment: You could tell your developers to stop being jerks and add a newline manually. Jesus.

Comment: Yeah the [lens](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807273/microsoft-alm-shared-remoting-remotecontainer-high-cpu) is a huge resource hog but the refs are nice.

Comment: @ThePhD extra lines + lens makes so little fit in the editor. One empty row without lens and no row with lens is sweet formatting imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: in Visual Studio 2015, CodeLens is now also available in Pro, so this issue only affects VS *2013* Pro.

Answer (score 6):

You asked [Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I am answering X.

**Add the blank lines in the code.** It solves the problem in Pro, and it also solves the problem of me (who never used code lens) not knowing which line belongs with which method.

```
15 references
public MaintenanceSettings Settings

31 references
protected override void Load

...
```

It's instantly easier to associate a lens with a member.

Comment: Yeah +1 that is the obvious way but not Y :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the blank line in there.

As well you can vote on the feature here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4150271-make-codelens-available-outside-of-ultimate

Microsoft does look at uservoice regarding Visual Studio.